# PHPmailer smtp GoDaddy problem "SMTP -> ERROR: DATA not accepted from server"

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

i'm having a problem with sending a mail with PHPmailer trough SMTP.

The mail is sended after 5 seconds, but it still prompts me the error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: DATA not accepted from server
```

but the mail is sended, but after 5 seconds, and i believe it has to do with a line from

**class.phpmailer.php**

```
public $Timeout       = 5;
```

because when i set this to 10 seconds, it waits 10 seconds ...

The problem is when i try to add an anchor hyperlink in the body html, for example, if i try to send

```
<a>nonlink</a> <br> <b>bold text</b>
```

it sends the mail with no problem and the html code is fine, but when i send

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">nonlink</a> <br> <b>bold text</b>
```

it gives me that error ....

my sending code is:

```
/*SEND MAIL*/

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//error_reporting(E_STRICT);
error_reporting(0);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('../../library/class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$Link = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Confirm user</a>';


$body             = $Link;
/*$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);*/

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtpout.europe.secureserver.net"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                   // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "smtpout.europe.secureserver.net"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 80;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "contact@mysite.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "thesecredpassword";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('contact@mysite.com"', 'The name');


$mail->Subject    = "Account Confirmation";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = $Username;
$mail->AddAddress($address, $Name);


if(!$mail->Send()) 
{
  /*echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;*/
  $error = true;
  $MailHasBeenNotSended = true;
}
```

Comment: Well i kinda figure it out, never trust GoDaddy, they are the worst hostig ever ...

Comment: This is covered in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). GoDaddy blocks outbound email access.